# multi language joomla site trouble in the cookie after Upgrade to 3.4.3

Tags: php, cookies, joomla, upgrade

I have Multi language joomla site (english/arabic/persian).
since the upgrade to v3.4.3 ,Cookies will no longer work.

That means default language is English. when I Browse Arabic language in frontend and click on Homepage Moved to the English site But must remain in the Arabic site.

how do I fix it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a link to your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
following path:

Extensions -> Plugin Manager ->  System - Language Filter 
and 
Remove URL Language Code -> Change to YES